# Can't open any tag pages

Tags: bug, tags

If I want to open [any tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) I get a error saying

> Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

in Chrome. In IE the site tries to load a few seconds but fails too.

<sub>I almost could not send the question because I got an error saying too many requests from my IP.</sub>

Comment: Yep, same here.